# Make vim stop splitting my Git commit messages

Tags: vim, git

Vim has this awful annoying habit of splitting my commit messages and automatically line-breaking them, rendering the second line with a red background for some reason.

[image]

How can I make vim *stop* doing this?

Comment: What are the vim variables `tw` and `wm` set to?  If they're set to non-zero values, you will get automatic line breaks inserted (by default at column 80).

Comment: This is Vim's built-in file type syntax highlighting for git commit messages trying to enforce a certain format for git messages. Your highlighting looks ugly because your git commit message is "ugly", in the sense that it does match the format Vim is expecting you to follow. Both the `gitcommit.vim` syntax highlighting module and the guidelines were written by Tim Pope. You can read them here: http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html. For a quick summary, make the first line a 50 character summary, leave a blank line, and then write your paragraphs below.

Comment: *(continued)...* So, this is not technically an answer, but you are supposed to make the highlighting not ugly by writing a properly formatted git commit message. Try to keep line one below 50 characters. Line 2 is supposed to be blank, which is why it is being colored a **BOLD RED** for "Warning: this text isn't supposed to be here!" Type the extended message beginning on line 3. Vim will automatically break your lines at 72 characters. Let it do so. If you need Vim to redo the line breaks because you did some editing, highlight the paragraph and do `gq` to fix the line breaks.

Comment: "If you need Vim to redo the line breaks because you did some editing, highlight the paragraph and do gq to fix the line breaks." Or navigate to the paragraph and type `gqip` to `gq` the `p`aragraph you're `i`n.

Comment: @jw013 Nonsense! The guy obviously does not like the Tim Pope's style pulled out of nowhere. The question is about how to make vim to do what the OP considers reasonable.

Answer (score 8):

I found the setting I needed in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim` was:

`setlocal textwidth=0`

Comment: Thank you. The other solution didn't work for me on OpenSUSE, but this one did.

Answer (score 7):

The filetype plugin enforces the preferred Git commit message style: Short title, and hard line breaks. If you don't agree with that style, undo the settings by putting the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`:

```
setlocal wrap formatoptions<
```

Comment: For those wondering how `formatoptions<` could be a valid argument to `setlocal`, the docs for [`:setlocal`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#:setlocal) explain that it will “Set the local value of {option} to its global value by copying the value.” So this command will remove the `t` and `l` flags (documented in [`fo-table`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table)) that the plugin adds to [`'formatoptions'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatoptions%27).